# Python multiprocessing map function error

Tags: python, parallel-processing, functional-programming, multiprocessing, functools

I have a simple multiprocessing example that I'm trying to create.  The ordinary map() function version works, but when changed to Pool.map, I'm getting a strange error:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
x = [1,2,3]
y = 10
f = lambda x,y: x**2+y

# ordinary map works:
map(partial(f,y=y),x)
# [11, 14, 19]

# multiprocessing map does not
p = Pool(4)
p.map(partial(f, y=y), x)
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 319, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Pickling error?  What is this exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arguments to `Pool.map` must be picklable. [Module-level functions are picklable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), but `partial(f, y=y)` is not defined at the module-level and so is not pickable.

There is a simple workaround:

```
def g(x, y=y):
    return f(x, y)

p.map(g, x)
```

---

Functions made with [`functools.partial` used to be unpickable](http://bugs.python.org/issue5228).
However, with Python2.7 or better, you can also define `g` (at the module level) using functools.partial:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import functools

def f(x, y):
    return x**2 + y

x = [1,2,3]
y = 10

g = functools.partial(f, y=y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool()
    print(p.map(g, x))
```

yields `[11, 14, 19]`. But note to get this result `f` had to be defined with `def` rather than `lambda`. I think this is because [`pickle` relies on "fully qualified" name references](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) to look up function object values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand---I have another script almost exactly the same, using partial, which does work, where this one doesn't.  What is it to say that something defined at the module-level?  Ahh, saw your update---yes, def versus lambda is exactly the difference between the one that worked and the one that doesn't.  Thanks!